# Failing to resolve promise within my websocket acknowledgement reconnect logic

Tags: javascript, timer, callback, promise, reconnect

I have a custom connect function that creates a promise I want resolved once I make a websocket call and receive an acknowledgement. The remote server may be up, it may be down, but if it's unavailable I want to keep trying until I'm successful.

```
const socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');

function createTimeoutCallback(callback)
{
  let called = false;

  let timerID = setTimeout(() => {
      if (called) return;
      called = true;
      callback(new TimeoutError());
    },
    60*1000);

  return function() {
    if (called) return;
    called = true;
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    callback.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}

async function myConnect()
{
  let mysocket = socketIOClient(url);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    mysocket.emit('clientconnect', args, createTimeoutCallback((resp) => {
      if (!(resp instanceof TimeoutError)) {

        // SUCCESS
        doSomething();
        resolve();
      }

      // We timed out, try again
      else {
        mysocket.close();
        setTimeout(myConnect, 60*1000);
      }  
    }));
  });
}

await connect();
// doSomething() gets called but we never get here
```

In the above code, if the endpoint is available, everything works fine. But I'm never returning from the myConnect() function when (1) I wait on its promise; and (2) the function needs to make several connection attempts (e.g., the server is not initially up); and (3) the endpoint finally comes back online and the connection succeeds. I suspect this has everything to do with me essentially abandoning the original promise on a reconnect attempt, but I don't want to reject it or the operation will prematurely fail.

Comment: try `setTimeout(() => myConnect().then(resolve), 60 * 1000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a workaround, which relies on an embedded function. With this technique there is only one promise which is always accessible and in scope, and the timer-based recursion (i.e., not stack-based) is always wrapped in that single promise that is never abandoned. I put this together before Jaromanda answered, so I can't confirm that his solution would work.

```
async function myConnect()
{
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    function innerConnect()
    {
      let mysocket = socketIOClient(url);

      mysocket.emit('clientconnect', args, createTimeoutCallback((resp) => {
        if (!(resp instanceof TimeoutError)) {

          // SUCCESS
          doSomething();
          resolve();
        }

        // We timed out, try again
        else {
          mysocket.close();
          setTimeout(innerConnect, 60*1000);
        }  
      }));
    }

    innerConnect();
  });
}
```